# React Get Another Component State

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state

Hello I had just started with react not much familiar with getting the state of another component in master component. Can anyone please help here out.

Scenario
I have 4 Component namely
**A, B, C, D**

- Here Component **B** act as a parent to **C and D** and Component
  **A** act as parent to **B**
- Now I want to read states of **B, C, D** in **Component A** and store
  them in state of **Component A**
- How can I perform this

Code Bellow for Reference

**Component A**

```
class A extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  Acomp:''
  };
}
render() {
return (
  <B/>
 )
}
}
export default A;
```

**Component B**

```
 class B extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  Bcomp:''
  };
}
render() {
return (
  <C/>
  <D/>
 )
}
}
export default B;
```

**Component C**

```
 class C extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  Ccomp:''
  };
}
render() {
return (
  <h1>i am Component C</h1>
 )
}
}
export default C
```

**Component D**

```
 class D extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  Dcomp:''
  };
}
render() {
return (
  <h1>i am Component D</h1>
 )
}
}
export default D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your state in Component A and pass them as props to Component B, C and D.

**Component A**

```js
class A extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    Acomp:'',
    Bcomp:'',
    Ccomp:'',
    Dcomp:'',
  };
 }

onChange = () =>{
//Write your function to change the value of state here
}


render() {
return (
  <B BComp = {this.state.Bcomp} CComp = {this.state.Ccomp} DComp = {this.state.Dcomp} onChange={this.onChange}/>
 )
}
}
export default A;
```

**Component B**

```js
class B extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  Bcomp:''
  };
}
render() {
return (
  <C Ccomp={this.props.CComp} onChange={this.onChange}/>
  <D Dcomp={this.props.DComp} />
 )
}
}
export default B;
```

And you can also pass your onChange function if required as props to **Components C & D**.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to lift your component state up through your components

See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html for more info!